Network Issue: Cellular Network Persistent until being super close to gateway, Messaging Apps Stuck on 'Connecting, connection super slow
Recently, I've noticed that whenever I connect my IPhone 6,  software version is 12.5.6, to Wi-Fi, the cellular network connection icon appears at the top of my screen instead of the Wi-Fi symbol until being super close to the gateway. Additionally, messaging apps like Messenger and others constantly show 'Connecting...' and fail to update messages. Only Whatsapp updates

It seems I have a super low descending speed:

I have looked up on the internet and found:

The expanded LTE connectivity on the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus is
improved to LTE Advanced, with support for over 20 LTE bands (seven
more than the iPhone 5s), for up to 150 Mbit/s download speed, and
VoLTE support.

Tonight I will try to test it with a different sim card
